# Code not executing after end of UIView.animate?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am in the `draw` function of an `UIView`. 
I want to draw a triangle, then after an animation, it's a mirror copy.
I can draw the triangle and the animation, or the triangle and it's copy, but when I add the code for drawing the copy in the "finished in" portion of the animation, it isn't drawn.
I don't know how to solve this problem...

Here is my code (with drawing of the mirror copy not showing anything).

```
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        let viewWidth = self.bounds.width
        let viewHeight = self.bounds.height

        context.setLineWidth(1.0)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.darkGray.cgColor)
        context.beginPath()
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let r = sqrt(viewHeight * viewHeight + viewWidth * viewWidth) * 0.50
        let p1 = CGPoint(x: viewWidth/2, y: 20 + r)
        var angle = CGFloat.pi * (90.0 + 30.0) / 180.0
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: p1.x + cos(angle) * r, y: p1.y - sin(angle) * r)
        angle = CGFloat.pi * 90.0 / 180.0
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: p1.x + cos(angle) * r, y: p1.y - sin(angle) * r)

        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addLine(to: p2)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.closeSubpath()

        context.addPath(path)
        context.strokePath()
        let trf =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)

        let sv = UIView(frame:self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(sv)
        let  shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
        shapeLayer.path = path
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        sv.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.display()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [],
         animations: {
         sv.transform = trf 
         }) { finished in         
        sv.removeFromSuperview()

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.scaleBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        context.translateBy(x:-viewWidth, y:0)
        context.addPath(path)
        context.strokePath()
        context.scaleBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        context.translateBy(x:viewWidth, y:0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: (Not an expert) but I wouldn't recommend truing to do animation within the `draw` function, instead, use `draw` to the draw the state you want to present and `animate` to move between those state. My "assumption" is that the `context` is no longer valid when the completion block is called

Comment: Try to call  sv.layoutIfNeeded()  to reload view inside the view animation method

Comment: It's not the animation the problem, with this code the animation works like a charm, it's just the `context.*` methods in the 'finish in" of the animation which doesn't produce any visual result...